# ARIMA model for annul data in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have census data in a csv file in this format for 30 or so zip codes:

zip-code, population, year
30875, 786532, 2011...

I want to create an arima model but I only have annual data for four years for each zip code and I don't think its enough data to accurately predict anything. Is there a way to do this in python or do I not have enough data?